# Oracle forms unable to type in text fields in query mode after migration to OFM 12C

Tags: oracle, weblogic12c, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

When typing in Oracle forms in text field in a query mode everything is deleted as soon as I type anything.

This behaviour is observed only after migration to OFM 12c and only in one particular form

Comment: No idea, but - try to recompile it "All" (Ctrl + Shift + K). Maybe it'll help.

Comment: Tried but same result

Comment: Whenever I click on any field in the background(Checked in the trace file) for update of some_field query is getting fired. This is not happening on 11g

Comment: Sorry, I wouldn't know why this is happening. Is there any trigger on that text field? Perhaps some Java code?

Comment: No particular field but all fields on the form. Is there any way to know how that query is getting fired ?

Answer (score 0):

Likely there is something in your code doing what you described, however consider this.

If all the text is selected (e.g. blue) when you enter the field then you type anything, existing text will be deleted.  This is exactly how any UI works.  The selected text must be deselected before typing if you want to retain it.

If you do not want the text automatically selected when you enter the field using the mouse, set FORMS_SELECT_ON_CLICK=0

Note that only works when using mouse to enter a field.  Refer to the Forms 12c New Features Guide for more information.

https://www.oracle.com/a/tech/docs/oracleforms-1221-newfeatures.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to resolve this issue. In query mode there is a forms property Locking mode whose value in 11g was Immediate but after changing the value to delayed in 12c its working fine.